# Firebase Google auth redirect_uri or https request

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I registered firebase project and add google auth. After that I added a web app, and then added redirect uri in google console (by copying auth domain in firebase and add "/__/auth/handler").

I created request, and pasted it in browser uri. After that I choose google account and it opens a web page with text:

> Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are -
>
> 1. Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO.
> 2. Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment.

Is my request incorrect or did I miss something?

My request:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=*****-*****.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://***-***.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler&scope=email